# Google App Engine - Connect to SQL Cloud Instance with php using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, mysqli

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to connect my `Google App Engine` project to my `Cloud SQL` instance using `php` with mysqli.

I found googles tutorial to be useless as it is with PDO and I couldn't get it to work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please add some info on what you have tried and what errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking Cam, here's what I (you) did...

Your mysqli creation statement should mimic below.

```
 new mysqli(null, "root", '<rootUserPassword>', "<dbName>", null, "/cloudsql/<instanceConnectionName>");
```

with root being the the default username assigned to the database

Note, this is for second generation cloud sql instances. I haven't tested this on first generation.